# Fail to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I'm trying to make it possible to add something to my guestbook through the website. But the problem is: I fail to insert into the database.
Using my WAMP server I can insert into it directly using the query down here.

I've tested the $name variables as well and they are properly filled in. I've switched $con and $sql. and I tried to format the query in different ways without{} with {}. But not even one option seems to work. The connection with my DBS works (I didn't include that part here). I tried mysql_query and mysqlI_query.

My WAMP server has php_mysqli enabled. And when I run this it doesn't give any errors.

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time
$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$comment= $_POST['comment'];
$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(name, email, comment, datetime) VALUES('{$name}','${email}','{$comment}','{$datetime}')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

// link to view guestbook page
    header('location:viewguestbook.php');

Comment: SQL injection.... Fail number one since the late '90's

Comment: You mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: Don't use mysql_*. Use [pdo](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=5029417480508117987#editor/target=post;postID=1990208301090788913;onPublishedMenu=posts;onClosedMenu=posts;postNum=10;src=postname) instead

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,And next time you must search mysqli prepared statements.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("insert...");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the problem in this statement

mysql_query($sql,$con);

problem 1: you are using mysqli and in above statement your are querying mysql.

problem 2: $con(connection variable is must be the first parameter)

Write this statement as folloing. that will solve the problem

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error do you get. You can do this:

```
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your insert query you have ${email} instead of {$email} and change mysql_query to mysqli_query
below is the code that should work

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time
$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$comment= $_POST['comment'];
$sql="INSERT INTO guestbook(name, email, comment, datetime) VALUES('{$name}','{$email}','{$comment}','{$datetime}')";
mysqli_query($sql,$con);
```